# How $\{am + pn : m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}=\langle 1 \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, gcd-and-lcm

I don't understand how $\{am + pn : m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is equal $\langle 1 \rangle$, doesn't $\langle 1 \rangle$ contains all integer of $\mathbb{Z}$? the passage I got it from -

> **Prime ideal property.** If $p$ is prime and the ideal $\langle p \rangle$ contains $\langle ab \rangle$, then
> $\langle p \rangle$ contains $\langle a \rangle$ or $\langle p \rangle$ contains $\langle b \rangle$
> Suppose $\langle a \rangle \nsubseteq \langle p \rangle$, so we have to prove $\langle b \rangle \subseteq \langle p \rangle$.
>
> **Proof:** Since the ideal $\{am + pn : m, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ contains both
> $\langle p \rangle$ and $\langle a \rangle$, and $\langle a \rangle \nsubseteq \langle p \rangle, {am +pn  : m,n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ can only
> equal $\langle 1 \rangle$. This means $1 = am+pn$ for some $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}...$

Comment: There's something else about $p$ and $a$ you are not saying. Is $p$ a prime and $a$ an integer not divisible by $p$? (Or they are coprime?)

Comment: @астонвіллатересалисбон I have edited plz chk...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fitst $\langle1\rangle=\Bbb{Z}$.

Next $\langle  a\rangle\not\subseteq \langle p\rangle$ implies $p\not\mid a$. Thus $a$ and $p$ are relatively prime. So there exists integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+py=1$. This gives any integer $n$ can be written as integral linear combination of $a$ and $p$, since $n=anx+pny$. Thus $\Bbb{Z}\subseteq \{am+pn:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$. And $\{am+pn:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}\subseteq \Bbb{Z}$ very easily. So $\Bbb{Z}=\langle1\rangle= \{am+pn:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: if you can have one you can have all of  z in Z, just by multiplying the equation bei z.

Comment: Why $\Bbb{Z}\subseteq \{am+pn:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ instead of $\Bbb{Z}= \{am+pn:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$, how $\Bbb{Z}\subset \{am+pn:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ according to your answer?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Comment: How $\Bbb{Z}\subset \{am+pn:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ in you answer?

Comment: Because $\{am+pm:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}\subseteq \Bbb{Z}$ holds trivially, so I didn't mention. Next any integer $n$ can be written as integral linear combination of $a$ and $p$ (as second last sentence of my answer shows) so $\Bbb{Z}\subseteq \{am+pm:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Mate, sorry to disturb u but "trivially" means nothing to a non-math student, you are missing the question, I understand $=$ but  I cant understand $\subset$ for $\mathbb{Z}$ which is the set of integers, is there an element in  $\{am + pn : m, n \}$ which can't be found in $ \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: trivially means very easily. Next $\Bbb{Z}=\{am+pn:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$ so $\Bbb{Z}$ is not a proper subset of $\{am+pn:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: That is what i am saying but you wrote $\subseteq$, why?

Comment: Yes, to show two set equal, $A=B$, we show it by showing $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$. Here put $A=\Bbb{Z}$ and $B=\{am+pm:m,n\in\Bbb{Z}\}$. Then my proof only includes the part $A\subseteq B$ part. And $B\subseteq A$ is easy, so this part I excluded.

Comment: mate probably  u are again using the wrong notation... perhaps, it should be like $A\subset B, B \subset A \implies A=B$

Comment: No, actually both are same. What you wrote is also correct and mine one is too.